# Special WebGL grid coloring using shaders

Tags: grid, webgl, shader

I have a grid with 1000 x 1000 rectangular cells with different color for each cell. I update the colors time to time. Size of rows and columns are changing with a constant. I read colors for the cells from an image. I draw the grid with single draw call. The performance is not good.

Is it possible to calculate vertex locations (x,y) and get colors from a texture using shaders?

Is there a demo or sample code with similar operations?

Comment: Show your effort and supply some codes about what's the question, but not only ask for a result.

Comment: I am new to WebGL. I searched Google for this but couldn't find an answer. I like to know if this is possible with shaders. I don't have a code using shaders. I just need a pointer to a sample demo or code. I appreciate an expert advise.

Comment: Do you really need vertices for each rectangle? Couldn't you simply load your original image into a texture, draw a single quad, and sample the colors from the texture?

Comment: I like to resize each pixel of the texture to a custom size rectangle. Cells in each row will have same height, cells in each column will have same width. It is like stretching the texture in a special way.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do within the shader.

Based on the *xy(z)* position of each vertex, proportional to the entire grid size, you could calculate the UV coordinate on the texture from which you need to fetch the color to shade the primitive.

Though, 1M rectangles probably is not such a great idea.

Have you considered [instancing](http://blog.tojicode.com/2013/07/webgl-instancing-with.html) rectangles to improve the perf?

Have you thought of doing it with particles?

Here are some links that may lead you towards some, better solution:

- [Photo Particles](http://lab.aerotwist.com/webgl/photoparticles/)
- [Surface](http://lab.aerotwist.com/webgl/surface/)